# Accessing cells from a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to get the cell data from a GridView, however i can access the first cell and get the data, however when i try and access the 2nd cell I get a blank string back. This happens under a click event.

```
public void btnBCM_ClickbtnSaveBCM_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   String value = GridView_Products.Rows[0].Cells[1].Text;
 }
```

GridView Image below

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you have plain text in the first column.
But the second column contains TextBox control

To access it use Controls collection

```
TextBox tb = GridView_Products.Rows[0].Cells[1].Controls[0] as TextBox;
if(tb!=null)
{
 String value = tb.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**try Data-keys on Grid tag and retrieve data key(column) value on row-command**

```
DataKeyNames="column_name"
```

(add attribute to grid)

```
C# code to get value

 string column_value= SafeConvert.ToString(GridView_Products.DataKeys[row.RowIndex‌​].Value);
```